# Understanding how to use multiprocessing pools

Tags: python, import, python-multiprocessing, global

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me out with some questions I have about multiprocessing and if I'm using the right approach for what I'm trying to do.

Here is some example code of what I've already written that I think shows what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


# Example Class that does some math things
class DoMath(object):
    def __init__(self, total):
        self.total = total

    def add(self, a, b):
        print("Addition: ", int(a+b))
        return int(a+b)

    def sub(self, a, b):
        print("Subtraction: ", int(a - b))
        return int(a-b)

    def totals(self, add, minus):
        self.total += (add + minus)
        print("Current Total: ", self.total)
        return int(self.total)


# Pool worker doing simple tasks, sleep is there so it doesn't complete instantly
def worker(a, b):
    time.sleep(1)
    add = values.add(a, b)
    sub = values.sub(a, b)
    values.totals(add, sub)
    return values


# Call back function
def callback(x):
    print('worker done')
    print(x.total)
    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    math_numbers = {"1": {"a": 1, "b": 1}, "2": {"a": 2, "b": 2}}

    values = DoMath(0)

    pool_size = 1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(
        processes=pool_size
    )

    for key, params_dict in math_numbers.items():
        test = pool.apply_async(worker, args=tuple(), kwds=params_dict, callback=callback)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(test)
    print(values.total)
```

When I run this, these are the results that I get:

```
Addition:  2
Subtraction:  0
Current Total:  2
worker done
2
Addition:  4
Subtraction:  0
Current Total:  6
worker done
6
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x104c5a0b8>
0
```

My first question revolves around how I instantiated the `DoMath` class on line 43. Starting the class up like this seems to work but my issue is on my actual code everything isn't in a single file and I haven't been able to figure out how to pass a class to the `apply_async` function. Trying to put it into the json dict does not seem to work for me. My actual code is building a connection pool so I can make REST requests to an API, currently the only way I've been able to get it to work is creating a new connection for every worker. This seems extremely inefficient, is there a better way to approach this? Here's an example of what I have vs what I'd like to do:

Current:

```
def worker(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    connection = connect(
        url=arg1,
        port=arg2
    )
    connection.api(do_something=arg3)
```

What I would like to do:

```
def worker(arg3, connection):
    connection.api(do_something=arg3)
```

Second, and this just might be a fundamental misunderstanding, but is there a way to process the results from these workers before the pool is completely finished? With my actual code I'm running upwards of 15000 workers and each one will return a list that's roughly 10k items long. I would like to have these written to a file, but rather than 15,000+ files being created I would like to have the process append them to files, rolling over to a new one every 100k lines. I realize I can force each worker to just write their outputs to a file, either inside the worker or in the callback but I'm worried that if I try to do the rollover process with multiple workers writing the same file at the same time some data may be lost or not properly committed.

On lines 56 and 57 of the first code block I shared, I'm a little confused on these results. I'm not really sure how I can use the `ApplyResult` object or what it's supposed to contain. Further more I really don't understand why the `values.total` object outside the workers is returning a 0 when both pools and callbacks returned the actual value of six. What's happening here?

Comment: The code in your question does not produces the results you say it prints except for the last two lines. You're also not seeing `NameError: name 'values' is not defined` exceptions occurring in `worker()` because the global variable only exists in the main process. An `ApplyResult` is the kind of object `apply_async()` returns. To get its value, use `print(test.get())`. Also note there will be different one each time `worker()` is invoked. I think the fundamental thing you're missing is that each process runs in a separate memory-space, which makes sharing data via global variables impossible.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6... not sure why it doesn't work for you. Running in pycharm gives the results back exactly as I pasted. Running in terminal returns:

```
('Addition: ', 2)
('Subtraction: ', 0)
('Current Total: ', 2)
worker done
2
('Addition: ', 4)
('Subtraction: ', 0)
('Current Total: ', 6)
worker done
6
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x10fc1a1d0>
0
```

Running `test.get().total()` does get me results. Your second response doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: FWIW I ran it using Python 3.7.3 via the Windows `cmd` shell. Try changing your `print(test)` to `print(test.get())` and see what happens and is printed. Regardless, the rest of my previous comment about separate name-spaces still applies.

Comment: The get() works and I was able to get that.

Your second comment doesn't really address my question. I get that the values object is inside the pool and a separate memory space. What I don't get is how I would use that object inside the pool if it was on a different `.py` file. I can't figure out how to pass it into the pool.

Comment: I don't think you get the separate memory spaces. The `values` object is _not_ inside the `pool`, and it doesn't even exist at all in the separate process running the `worker()` function. I suggest you read [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the online documentation. This is also mentioned in the [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) section above that.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing a poor job of explaining myself or using incorrect terminology. I realize that the memory space is different. What I don't understand is how the values object being built relates to how it's being used inside the pool. If you comment out the line `values = DoMath(0)` the entire script fails with the error `NameError: name 'values' is not defined`. It's not really an issue on this script to create the object like I have, but when I have something split out into multiple scripts unless the DoMath function is on the same page as the worker function I can't get it to work.